# Highlighting parent menu from router-link in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have developed a split sidebar menu. On the left there is icons which when pressed activate the menu bar on the right side for the submenu items. The submenu contains the router-link tags which I am able to tap into the active class of the selected link to highlight it. The issue is I need to apply the active class to the left icon bar as well since that is the parent menu. Once the application is loaded when you click the icons the active class will become active if the item is selected. My issue is purely during load because if someone types in the URL the custom router link the left sidebar does not have any functionality linking it to the router since the links are in the right part of the sidebar. Any methodology built into vue to handle something like this? If not is there another method I could try?

My sidebar component code is below. The code basically creates two sides, the icon side and the menu side. The icons and menu's are developed using v-for and looping through the data set which provides the links and icons to use.

```
<template id="side-navigation">
    <div :class="theme">
        <nav :class="sidebarcontainer">
            <div class="sidebar-left">
                <div class="arms-icon">
                </div>
                <div class="main-menu-items">
                    <ul>
                        <li v-for="(item,i) in MainNavLinks"
                            :key="i"
                            :class="{'active-main-menu-item': i === activeIconIndex}"
                            v-on:click="selectIconItem(i)">
                            <a>
                                <i :class="item.icon"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="bottom-menu-items">
                    <ul>
                        <li v-for="(item,i) in FeaturesNavLinks"
                            :key="i"
                            :class="{ 'active-main-menu-item': i+MainNavLinks.length === activeIconIndex}"
                            v-on:click="selectIconItem(i+MainNavLinks.length)">
                            <a>
                                <i :class="item.icon"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sidebar-right" :class="{'active-right-sidebar' : isIconActive}">
                <div class="sidebar-content">
                    <div class="searchbarcontent">
                        <div class="inputWithIcon">
                            <input placeholder="Search" id="sub-nav-seachbar" class="searchbar" type="text">
                            <i class="fas fa-search" id="searchicon-btn"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div v-for="(item,i) in MainNavLinks"
                         :key="i"
                         :class="{'active-sub-menu-item' : i === activeIconIndex}"
                         class="right-menu-content">
                        <ul>
                            <li v-for="(SubNavLink,i) in item.SubNavLinks"
                                class="sub-nav-group">
                                <h4 class="sub-nav-header">
                                    {{SubNavLink.SubNavHeader}}
                                </h4>
                                <ul>
                                    <li v-for="(SubNavMenuItem,i) in SubNavLink.SubNavMenuItems"
                                        class="sub-nav-items">
                                        <router-link :to="SubNavMenuItem.link"><span class="sub-menu-icons"><i :class="SubNavMenuItem.icon"></i></span>{{SubNavMenuItem.title}}</router-link>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

    </div>
</template>
<script>
    Vue.component('side-navigation', {
        template: '#side-navigation',
        methods: {
            selectIconItem(i) {
                if (this.activeIconIndex === i) {
                    if (this.isIconActive === true) {
                        this.isIconActive = false;
                    } else {
                        this.isIconActive = true;
                    }
                } else {
                    this.activeIconIndex = i;
                    this.isIconActive = true;
                }
            },
        },

        data() {
            return {
                theme: 'color',
                activeIconIndex: null,
                isIconActive: false,
                sidebarcontainer: 'sidebar-container',
                MainNavLinks: [
                    {
                        name: 'Dashboard',
                        link: '/',
                        icon: 'fa fa-th-large fa-lg',
                        SubNavLinks: [
                            {
                                SubNavHeader: 'Dash Category 1',
                                SubNavMenuItems: [{
                                    title: 'Item 1',
                                    link: '/',
                                    icon: 'fas fa-list-ul'
                                },
                                {
                                    title: 'Item 2',
                                    link: '/item2',
                                    icon: 'fas fa-list-ul'
                                }]
                            },
                            {
                                SubNavHeader: 'Dash Category 2',
                                SubNavMenuItems: [{
                                    title: 'Item 3',
                                    link: '/item3',
                                    icon: 'fas fa-list-ul'
                                },
                                {
                                    title: 'Item 4',
                                    link: '/item4',
                                    icon: 'fas fa-list-ul'
                                }]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Reviews',
                        link: '/Reviews',
                        icon: 'far fa-clipboard fa-lg',
                        SubNavLinks: [
                            {
                                SubNavHeader: 'Reviews Category 1',
                                SubNavMenuItems: [{
                                    title: 'Item 1',
                                    link: '/item1',
                                    icon: 'fas fa-list-ul'
                                },
                                {
                                    title: 'Item 2',
                                    link: '/item2',
                                    icon: 'fas fa-list-ul'
                                }]
                            },
                            {
                                SubNavHeader: 'Reviews Category 2',
                                SubNavMenuItems: [{
                                    title: 'Item 3',
                                    link: '/item3',
                                    icon: 'fas fa-list-ul'
                                },
                                {
                                    title: 'Item 4',
                                    link: '/item4',
                                    icon: 'fas fa-list-ul'
                                }]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Upload',
                        link: '/Upload',
                        icon: 'fa fa-upload fa-lg',
                        SubNavLinks: [
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Analytics',
                        link: '/Analytics',
                        icon: 'fas fa-chart-line fa-lg',
                        SubNavLinks: [
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Files',
                        link: '/Files',
                        icon: 'far fa-folder-open fa-lg',
                        SubNavLinks: [
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                FeaturesNavLinks: [
                    {
                        name: 'Notifications',
                        link: '/',
                        icon: 'fas fa-bell fa-lg'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Chat',
                        link: '/',
                        icon: 'fas fa-comment-alt fa-lg'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Email',
                        link: '/',
                        icon: 'fas fa-envelope fa-lg'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Profile',
                        link: '/',
                        icon: 'fas fa-user fa-lg'
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
     })
</script>
<style scoped>
    .sidebar-container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        box-shadow: 2px 0px 4px -1px rgb(0 0 0 / 15%);
        position: sticky;
    }

/*left icon section of sidebar*/
    .sidebar-left {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        width: 100px;
        position: relative;
        height: 100vh;
        overflow-y: auto;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }

    .color .sidebar-left {
        background-color: #ff7100;
    }

    .light .sidebar-left {
        border-right: 1px solid #ebedf3;
    }

    .main-menu-items {
        padding: 20px 20px;
        flex-grow: 1;
    }
    .sidebar-left ul {
        padding: 0px;
    }
    .sidebar-left li {
        list-style-type: none;
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .sidebar-left a {
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        border-radius: .42rem;
    }
    .color .sidebar-left a:hover > *, .color .sidebar-left a:hover {
        background-color: #da6000f7;
        color: #fff !important;
    }

    .light .sidebar-left a:hover > *, .light .sidebar-left a:hover {
        background-color: #f3f6f9;
        color: #ff7d44 !important;
    }

    .color .active-main-menu-item a > *, .color .active-main-menu-item a {
        background-color: #da6000f7;
        color: #fff !important;
    }

    .light .active-main-menu-item a > *, .light .active-main-menu-item a {
        background-color: #f3f6f9;
        color: #ff7d44 !important;
    } 

    .color .sidebar-left i {
        color: #fff;
    }

    .light .sidebar-left i {
        color: #a5a5a5;
    }
   
    /*right sidebar styling*/

    .sidebar-right {
        width: 0px;
        position: relative;
        transition: all 1s;
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 100vh;
        overflow-y: auto;
    }
    .active-right-sidebar {
        width: 325px;
        transition: all 1s;
    }
    .sidebar-content{
        padding:20px;
    }
    .right-menu-content {
        display: none;
        overflow: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
        padding: 0px 20px;
    }
    .active-sub-menu-item {
        display: block;
    }
    /*sidebar searchbar*/
    .searchbar {
        width: 100%;
        height: 40px;
        border: 0px;
        border-radius: 40px;
        outline: none;
        padding: 8px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        transition: 0.3s;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        background-color: #e6e6e6;
    }


    .inputWithIcon input[type="text"], .inputWithIcon input[type="password"] {
        padding-left: 35px;
    }

    .inputWithIcon {
        position: relative;
        height: 40px;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .searchbarcontent {
        padding: 0px 20px;
        display: flex;
        height: 50px;
        width: 100%;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    #searchicon-btn {
        padding: 9px 25px 9px 5px;
        top: 4px;
        color: #aaa;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .sidebar-right ul {
        padding: 0px;
    }

    .sidebar-right li {
        list-style-type: none;
    }

    .sidebar-right a {
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .sub-nav-header {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        height: 50px;
        font-size: 1rem;
        font-weight: 700;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        letter-spacing: .3px;
        color: #7e8299;
    }

    .sub-nav-items {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        height: 45px;
        font-size: .9rem;
        font-weight: 600;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        letter-spacing: .3px;
    }

    .sub-nav-items a {
        color: #7f818d;
    }

    .sub-nav-group{
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
    .sub-menu-icons {
        width: 30px;
        padding-right: 20px;
    }

    .router-link-exact-active {
        color: #ff7100 !important;
    }

    /*scrollbar*/
    /* custom scrollbar */
    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 20px;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
        background-color: transparent;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        background-color: #00000014;
        border-radius: 20px;
        border: 6px solid transparent;
        background-clip: content-box;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
        background-color: #0000001f;
    }

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Use [nested routes](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html).

Parent `<router-link>`'s should have the class `.router-link-active`.

The exact `<router-link>` should have `.router-link-exact-active`.

Check out [this code](https://jsfiddle.net/8xrk1n9f/) for an interactive example.

Comment: I am going over this example but I am struggling to understand how the additional router-links that are tied to the exact link do not show up in the url as if they are being clicked. Basically the parent menu shouldnt impact the history or the url above unless an item in the sub menu is actually clicked. Does that make sense?

Comment: I tested the methods in that link but they all seems to impact the URL and as noted above I do not think the paten menu should really act as a link itself right? Of all the dashboards I have seen split menus like this the left menu doesn’t act as a link itself. Stumped on how to solve this via vuejs.